# How can I read in from two files,insert new columns, and compute functions like mean if there are blank values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this file called 'test.txt' and it looks like this:

```
3.H5 5.40077
2.H8 7.75894
3.H6 7.60437
3.H5 5.40001
5.H5 5.70502
4.H8 7.55438
5.H1' 5.43574
5.H6 7.96472
""
""
""
""
""
""
6.H6 7.96178
6.H5 5.71068
""
""
7.H8 8.29385
7.H1' 6.01136
""
""
""
""
8.H5 5.51053
8.H6 7.67437
```

I want to see if the values in the first column are the same (i.e.: if 8.H5 occurs more than once), and if they are, I want to count how many times and take their average. I want my output to look like this:

```
 Atom  nVa  predppm   avgppm    stdev    delta    QPred   QMulti   qTotal
 1.H1'   1    5.820    5.737    0.000    0.000    0.985    1.000    0.995
 2.H1'   1    5.903    5.892    0.000    0.000    0.998    1.000    0.999
 3.H1'   1    5.549    5.454    0.000    0.000    0.983    1.000    0.994
 4.H1'   1    5.741    5.737    0.000    0.000    0.999    1.000    1.000
 6.H1'   1    5.543    5.600    0.000    0.000    0.990    1.000    0.997
 8.H1'   1    5.363    5.359    0.000    0.000    0.999    1.000    1.000
10.H1'   1    5.378    5.408    0.000    0.000    0.995    1.000    0.998
11.H1'   1    5.501    5.497    0.000    0.000    0.999    1.000    1.000
14.H1'   1    5.962    5.893    0.000    0.000    0.988    1.000    0.996
```

Right now, my code reads from `test.txt` and computes the count and the mean of the values and gives an output which looks like this (`output.txt`):

```
Atom  nVa    avgppm    
1.H1'   1     5.737    
2.H1'   1     5.892   
3.H1'   1     5.454    
4.H1'   1     5.737    
6.H1'   1     5.600
```

But it does not account for the `""` rows, how can I get my code to skip lines that have `""`?

I also have a file called test2.txt which looks like this:

```
5.H6 7.72158 0.3
6.H6 7.70272 0.3
7.H8 8.16859 0.3
8.H6 7.65014 0.3
9.H8 8.1053 0.3
10.H6 7.5231 0.3
12.H6 7.72805 0.3
13.H6 8.02977 0.3
14.H6 7.69624 0.3
17.H8 7.24899 0.3
16.H8 8.27957 0.3
18.H6 7.6439 0.3
19.H8 7.65501 0.3
20.H8 7.78512 0.3
21.H8 8.06057 0.3
22.H8 7.47677 0.3
23.H6 7.7306 0.3
24.H6 7.80104 0.3
```

I want to read in values from the first column of `test.txt` and values from the first column in `test2.txt` and see if they are the same (i.e.: if 20.H8 = 20.H8) and if they are, I want to insert a column in my `output.txt` between the `nVa` column and the `avgppm` column, and put in the values from `test2.txt`. How can I insert a column into this output file which also accounts for the blank spaces, by not using those lines?

This is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys

test = 'test.txt'
test2 = 'test2.txt'


df = pd.read_csv(test, sep = ' ', header = None)
df.columns = ["Atom","ppm"]
gb = (df.groupby("Atom", as_index=False)
        .agg({"ppm":["count","mean"]})
        .rename(columns={"count":"nVa", "mean":"avgppm"}))
gb.head()
gb.columns = gb.columns.droplevel()
gb = gb.rename(columns={"":"Atom"})
gb.to_csv("output.txt", sep =" ", index=False)

df2 = pd.read_csv(test2, sep = r'/s+', header = None)
df2.columns = ["Atoms","ppms","error"]

shift1 = df2["Atoms"]
shift2 = df2["ppms"]
```

I'm not exactly sure how to proceed.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't account for the "" rows"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To drop the row with `""` as the values, use the `dropna` method of the data frame.  You can follow this by `reset_index` to reset the row counts

```
df = pd.read_csv(test, sep = ' ', header = None)
df.columns = ["Atom","ppm"]
df = df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)

gb = ...
```

To find matching values, you can use `merge` method and compare the columns of interest.

```
df2 = pd.read_csv(test2, sep = r'/s+', header = None)
df2.columns = ["Atoms","ppms","error"]
gb.merge(df2, left_on='Atom', right_on='Atoms', how='left').drop(['Atoms','ppms'], axis=1)
```

This will leave you with `NA` values if the value in `gb` is not in `df2`.

Comment: Thanks! But I just tried this code and I don't see what it did, I'm getting the same output as before, and I don't know where you are inserting a column between `nVa` and `avgppm` in my output file which inserts the values from the second column of `test2.txt` after checking the matching values between `test.txt` and `test2.txt`

Answer (score 0):

A left `merge()` should be able to bring `df` and `df2` together the way you want.

```
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep=" ", header=None, names=["Atom", "ppm"])
df2 = pd.read_csv("test2.txt", sep=" ", header=None, names=["Atom", "ppms", "error"])

gb = df.groupby("Atom").agg(["count", "mean"])
gb.merge(df2.set_index("Atom"), how="left", left_index=True, right_index=True)

       (ppm, count)  (ppm, mean)     ppms  error
Atom                                            
2.H8              1      7.75894      NaN    NaN
3.H5              2      5.40039      NaN    NaN
3.H6              1      7.60437      NaN    NaN
4.H8              1      7.55438      NaN    NaN
5.H1'             1      5.43574      NaN    NaN
5.H5              1      5.70502      NaN    NaN
5.H6              1      7.96472  7.72158    0.3
6.H5              1      5.71068      NaN    NaN
6.H6              1      7.96178  7.70272    0.3
7.H1'             1      6.01136      NaN    NaN
7.H8              1      8.29385  8.16859    0.3
8.H5              1      5.51053      NaN    NaN
8.H6              1      7.67437  7.65014    0.3
```

Note: It doesn't seem that you even need `dropna()` for the missing rows in `df`.  `read_csv()` interprets the `""` values as `NaN`, and `groupby()` ignores `NaN` when grouping.